# Xcode: Library file not found in existing project, where is it expected?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, frameworks, sstoolkit

I am currently working into an existing project that uses the SS Toolkit. 
The previous developer told me he had one folder in his home library folder called sstoolkit where he had the SS Toolkit files.
I downloaded the latest version of SS Toolkit and copied it to ~/Library/ss toolkit/ as it was suggested.

However, Xcode still complains with the error message:

```
#import <sstoolkit/SSLoadingView.h> <---- here is the error:

sstoolkit/SSLoadingView.h File not found.
```

How can I find the information where Xcode expects the files to be located?! My plan is just to look up where XCode searches for the file and the to copy it there.

Thanks for your help and best regards.

Comment: You wrote `~/Library/ss toolkit/`: is the space after ss a typo? if not, that's probably an issue...

Comment: It looks like a typo, it should read `#import <SSToolkit/SSLoadingView.h>`. Case is important here. See http://sstoolk.it/

Comment: I made a typo here, i don't have the space in the directory folder.

Comment: @ott--: Hm, I don't think that I should change anything at the code. It compiles on other machines. The previous developer is not reachable....

Comment: If he renamed the directory, then leave that way. Just make sure it matches.

Comment: I added to the Header Search Path now the absolute path to my Libarys Folder. Now I get a new error: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SSLoadingView", referenced from:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure *Header Search Path* points to the folder containing SSToolkit. Note that SSToolkit should contain a folder named `SSToolkit`.

In your example you have SSToolkit in `~/Library/SSToolkit`. `SSLoadingView.h` should exist at `~/Library/SSToolkit/SSToolkit/SSLoadingView.h` and your *Header Search Path* should be `~/Library/SSToolkit`.

Also, I would strongly recommend placing SSToolkit in your project's directory so you can be sure you have the version you are expecting in each project as well as have it in your version control. See http://sstoolk.it for instructions on how to add it as a git submodule. That is the recommended workflow.

Hopefully that helps.